# Show a tip for Options with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which adds a bit of text below the select box when an item is selected.  However it I can only get it to show the value of the select box.  Is there any way I could get this to show a 3rd value?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dropdownTip(value){
    console.log(value);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = value;
    }</script>

<select onChange="dropdownTip(this.value)" name="search_type" style="margin-right:10px;         margin-top:2px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Client 1</option>    
    <option value="2">Client 2</option>
    <option value="3">Client 3</option>
    <option value="4">Client 4</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

For example, I would like to add something like "Always remember to ask for the full name" on client one, and "Never ask for last name" On client 2.

Comment: is some of this answers right? Mark it please.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dropdownTip(value){
    var preamble = 'default preamble';
    if(value == 'Client 2') {
       preamble = 'Never ask for last name on ';
    } 
    if (value == 'Client one') {
       preamble =  'Always remember to ask for the full name';
     }
    console.log(value);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = preamble + value;
    }</script>

<select onChange="dropdownTip(this.value)" name="search_type" style="margin-right:10px;         margin-top:2px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Client 1</option>    
    <option value="2">Client 2</option>
    <option value="3">Client 3</option>
    <option value="4">Client 4</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use html5 [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attributes.

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z6wH/).

javascript:

```
window.dropdownTip = function (obj) {

    console.log(obj);
    console.log(obj.value);

    var sel = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex];
    console.log(sel.getAttribute('data-desc'));

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = obj.value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += sel.getAttribute('data-desc');
}
```

html:

```
<body>
    <select onchange="dropdownTip(this);" name="search_type" id="selector">
        <option selected="selected" value="1" data-desc="test 1">Client 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-desc="test 2">Client 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-desc="test 3">Client 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-desc="test 4">Client 4</option>
    </select>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```